# Error Code: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, mysql-workbench

I'm trying to create a health management DB, I get this error. What is the problem?

```
-- table glocation

CREATE TABLE `MOH`.`glocation` (
`street` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
`city` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
`state` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
`geolocation` INT(8),
PRIMARY KEY (`street`, `city`, `state`));

-- table patient

CREATE TABLE `MOH`.`patient` (
`PID` INT(6) zerofill UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`first_name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
`last_name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
`sex` VARCHAR(10),
`b_insurance` VARCHAR(45),
`s_insurance` VARCHAR(45),
`education` VARCHAR(20),
`job` VARCHAR(20),
`street` VARCHAR(20),
`city` VARCHAR(20),
`state` VARCHAR(20),
`date_of_birth` date,
`license` boolean,
PRIMARY KEY (`PID`),
CONSTRAINT `street`
  FOREIGN KEY (`street`)
  REFERENCES `MOH`.`glocation` (`street`),
CONSTRAINT `city`
  FOREIGN KEY (`city`)
  REFERENCES `MOH`.`glocation` (`city`),
CONSTRAINT `state`
  FOREIGN KEY (`state`)
  REFERENCES `MOH`.`glocation` (`state`));
```

The error is:

> CREATE TABLE `MOH`.`patient` (...)    Error Code: 1215. Cannot add
>   foreign key constraint

Comment: Why are you creating a multi-column primary key in MOH.glocation instead of just using the geolocation field? Why are you duplicating the fields (street, city, state) from the MOH.glocation in MOH.patient instead of using geolocation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I should think it's because you're trying to make `patient.street`, `patient.city` and `patient.state` foreign keys *individually,* but they aren't *independently* primary keys in `glocation`.

Try making the *combination* of columns a *single* foreign key, as in

```
CONSTRAINT location
  FOREIGN KEY (street, city, state)
  REFERENCES glocation (street, city, state)
```

which I think makes more sense in the context of your project anyway. (The three independent constraints you tried to define would have allowed nonsense combinations like `'El Camino Real', 'New York City', 'Florida'` as long as *each* value *independently* existed in `glocation`.)